# is the variable of the entity a clone from the variable range?

Tags: groovy, optaplanner

```
class Lecture {
    Teacher t1 = new Teacher()
    Teacher t2 = new Teacher()
    Teacher t3 = new Teacher()


    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = ["teacherRange"])
    Teacher teacher 


    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "teacherRange")
    public List<Teacher> getTeacherRange() {
        [t1, t2, t3]
    }

}
```

This code is written in groovy.

When I was debug, I found the object from teacher has different hash code from t1, t2, t3, I think the teacher is the clone object,
is that right?

So, if I want to update the teacher assigned to the teacher, how?  because I could not update t1, t2, t3 in anywhere else

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you mean a case in which the problem changes *during* `solve()` (for example a new teacher or a teacher change)? That's real-time planning, so ProblemFactChange as Nick explains. Do you mean a case where you're surprised that a planning clone (see docs section on that) happened? Normally the Lecture instance would be planning cloned and the Teacher instance would not - except if they have a list of Lectures or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Looking the documentation of PlanningVariable I read:

> It is specified on a getter of a java bean property of a
>   PlanningEntity class.

https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/api/domain/variable/PlanningVariable.html

So, you have to annotate a method not a variable. Your code must be something similar to:

```
class Lecture {
  Teacher t1 = new Teacher()
  Teacher t2 = new Teacher()
  Teacher t3 = new Teacher()

  private Teacher teacher 
  @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = ["teacherRange"])
  Teacher getTeacher(){
      teacher
  } 
  void setTeacher(Teacher teacher){
    this.teacher=teacher
  }

  @ValueRangeProvider(id = "teacherRange")
  public List<Teacher> getTeacherRange() {
    [t1, t2, t3]
  }
}
```

Comment: The documentation you are referring to is quite old, the latest documentation (https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.11.0.Final/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/api/domain/variable/PlanningVariable.html) states it's also possible to define the annotation on a field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are referring to when you say you want to "update the teacher assigned to the teacher", but if you want to make a change to one of the properties of your variable or problem fact, take a look at [ProblemFactChange](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.11.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#problemFactChange)

Comment: @nick update the teacher assigned to the lecture. i mean the teacher assigned to the lecture, is not the instance from the teacher fact, if there are the same object, they should have the same hash code....